# Magento cloud ssh denied for db:dump

Tags: magento2, cli, ssh, cloud, magento2-cloud

I need to install an existing Magento Cloud project locally using cli but facing issues with database dump.
Indeed here's the error I get :

```
  Hello xxxxxxx (UUID: xxxxxxx), you successfully connected, but the service xxxxxxx doesn't exist or you do not have access to it  
  xxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.magento.cloud: Permission denied (publickey).
```

More details :
- cli logged in to magento-cloud with an account having access to the project
- cloud user is **super admin** on **master** environnment
- **ssh key** has been added with `magento-cloud ssh-key:add` command
- I've been able to clone the project without any problem
- same error when trying to use `magento-cloud ssh`

If you have any ideas why ssh is working for git clone but not for direct connection or if you think about a workaround, I'm listening :)

[EDIT] I've seen on [**platform.sh** doc](https://docs.platform.sh/development/ssh.html#troubleshoot-ssh) that a redeployment is necessary to activate new ssh keys but it's not mentionned in magento cloud doc, what do you think about it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, after trying a redeployment on master, SSH now works perfectly !

To trigger a new production deployment, you simply have to merge any code or empty commit (`git commit --allow-empty -m "User xxx added"`) to master (see https://docs.platform.sh/dedicated-gen-2/architecture/deploying.html#deploying-to-production-and-staging).

Answer (score 0):

Can you please guide us on how did you perform the redeployment steps?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/208031)

Comment: Hello, you can redeploy by simply creating a new commit (even an empty one) and merge it to your project master branch, I've updated my previous comment to add details and documentation link.